# Local windows service not accessible to the remote computer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, windows-services

I am deploying a React app on a virtual machine, windows server 2012, hosted on the IIS server. The website is successfully running on the local server. When I try to access the website through a remote computer, the static components are rendered successfully, but the API doesn't work. The API is written in node.js and installed as a windows service on the windows server with the port number 5000.

I put localhost:5000 as the axios base url in react. But when I try to access from the remote computer, the computer is reading from its own localhost instead of the server's localhost.

Even if I change the axios base url from localhost to the server's ip address, it still cannot read the API properly.

My questions are as follows:

1. How to make the remote computer reads from the server's localhost without putting the server's ip address?
2. How to make the local server's windows service accessible to other computers?
3. What is the best practice to store the API base url in React in production? (store in.env, config, etc...)?

Answer (score 0):

I just solve the issue and I post the answer here for anyone who has the same issue.

Windows
Create a firewall rule (Windows only)
You need to allow other computers to connect through your firewall.

1. Open the Windows Firewall
2. Go to “Inbound Rules”
3. Click “New Rule”
4. Select “Port” to make a port rule
5. Under “Specific local ports”, enter 80 and 8000 (for me it's port 5000)
6. Select “Allow the connection”
7. Click “next” then choose a name for your rule.

Source of this answer: [https://otree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/server/adhoc.html#windows][1]